# How many ways can 9 dice fall unordered?

Tags: combinatorics, dice

I am a little confused about why two different approaches are giving two different answers.

The most natural approach for me is to consider the dice ordered at first, so we have 6 options for the first dice, 6 for the second ... and so on so we get
$$6^9$$
But since it is unordered we don't care which dice is the first we can mod out by $9!$ giving 
$$\frac{6^9}{9!}$$
But we can also solve it using the stars and bars method (allowing 0s for any of the buckets) so we get
$$\binom{14}5$$
Why are these different?

Comment: Notice that $6^9 = 2^9\cdot 3^9$ only has prime factors of $2$ and $3$, however $9!$ has $7$ and $5$ as prime factors among others.  $\frac{6^9}{9!}$ is therefore not even an integer!  There is no way then that it counts *anything* as the answer to any counting problem is always an integer.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{6^9}{9!}$ does not give the correct answer for *any* situation, because some ordered combinations of dice rolls remain invariant under certain permutations – for example, any roll where all dice show the same number remains invariant under *any* permutation. Therefore $9!$ is not the correct factor to divide by.

$\binom{14}5$ is the correct answer.